# Manually set the focus on input element in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I create one input element and on click show the list of items after selecting any item list get hide.

But the focus is not on that element it get down,

So I just want to manually set the focus on input element when radio button list get hide.

Here is use the following code,

**View**

```
 <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-click="showDays()">
            <span class="input-label black-text">DAYS</span>
            <span class="input-ctrl">
            <input type="text" id="days" readonly  ng-model="data_day" focus-on="!daysflag">
            </span>
 </label>
 <div ng-show="daysflag">
          <ion-radio icon="ion-ios-checkmark" ng-model="data_day" ng-value="{{day}}" ng-repeat="day in days" ng-click="hideDayFlag()">{{day}}</ion-radio>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
        $scope.days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

        $scope.showDays = function() {
          $scope.daysflag = true;
        }
        $scope.hideDayFlag = function() {
          $scope.daysflag = false;
        }
```

**Directive**

```
 .directive('focusOn',function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                link : function($scope,$element,$attr) {
                    $scope.$watch($attr.focusOn,function(_focusVal) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            _focusVal ? $element[0].focus() :
                                $element[0].blur();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong to use the function `scope.$watch`. `scope.$watch` is used to track changes in the $scope.

See detail [explanation](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/watch).

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/9o15Ldp6/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isFocus = false;
  })
  .directive('focusOn', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        focusOn: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, $element, $attr) {
        scope.$watch('focusOn', function(_focusVal) {
          _focusVal ? $element[0].focus() :
            $element[0].blur();
        });
        $element.on("focus", function() {
          scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            scope.focusOn = true;
          });
        });
        $element.on("blur", function() {

          scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            scope.focusOn = false;
          });
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <input ng-model="vm.countRow" focus-on="vm.isFocus">
    <input type="button" value="Focus" ng-click="vm.isFocus=true">
    <input type="button" value="Blur" ng-click="vm.isFocus=false">{{vm.isFocus}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but For the my issue its not working

Comment: i have issue when ng-show get false and list get hide then focus goes to directly on html input field

Comment: To solve your issue, you create directive `focusOn`. This directive doesn't work! You write *So I just want to manually set the focus on input element when radio button list get hide*. And i do it. Manually set focus on input element.

Comment: focusing is work but it not scroll up on that element

Comment: On chrome v49 scroll up on focus element.